# Is it possible to alias bean class names in Spring?

Tags: spring, syntax

I have a string property which looks similar to the following example:

```
<property name="mappingData">
  <list>                
    <bean class="com.company.product.longNamingStandard.migration.extractor.FieldMapping">
      <property name="elementName" value="entitlement.user"/>
      <property name="mapping" value="DocUsers"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.company.product.longNamingStandard.migration.extractor.FieldMapping">
      <property name="elementName" value="entitlement.contributor"/>
      <property name="mapping" value="DocContributors"/>
    </bean>
  </list>
</property>
```

The long class name(s) effect readability & also create a refactoring overhead.

Is it possible to alias the class name and use a short name to declare the beans? Or is there an alternate best practice I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about using the combination of id attributes on beans & ref elements. I do use this however I was hoping to find a way to clean up the bean declarations themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late for you, but hopefully useful for others:

You can use parent beans to accomplish this.
First declare a parent bean as a template:

```
<bean id="FieldMapping" class="com.company.product.longNamingStandard.migration.extractor.FieldMapping"/>
```

Then use it elsewhere, using the parent attribute.

```
<property name="mappingData">
  <list>                
    <bean parent="FieldMapping">
      <property name="elementName" value="entitlement.user"/>
      <property name="mapping" value="DocUsers"/>
    </bean>
    <bean parent="FieldMapping">
      <property name="elementName" value="entitlement.contributor"/>
      <property name="mapping" value="DocContributors"/>
    </bean>
  </list>
</property>
```

Please note my convention here is to use upper case id's here for the parent template beans.

Answer (score 1):

each `<bean/>` comes with an attribute of `name` and `id` to help you reference those beans later in your configuration.

I would suggest using the `id` for declaring the bean.

your config could look like:

```
<bean id="fooBean" class="com.example.foo"/>
<bean id="barBean" class="com.example.bar"/>

<list>
   <ref>fooBean</ref>
   <ref>barBean</ref>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to represent your mapping in some short form, and then convert it to the list of `FieldMapping`s. For example, mappings from your snippet may be represented as a map.

As a theoretic exercise in Spring 3 you can do this with [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (if `FieldMapping` has the apropriate constructor):

```
<util:map id = "m">
    <entry name = "entitlement.user" value = "DocUsers" />
    <entry name = "entitlement.contributor" value = "DocContributors" />
</util:map>
...
<property name = "mappingData" 
    value = "#{m.![new com.company.product.longNamingStandard.migration.extractor.FieldMapping(key, value)]}" />
```

If this expression is too obscure, you may implement a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) to take a short form of your mapping data (for example, a map, as in this example) and return a configured list of `FieldMapping`s:

```
<property name = "mappingData">
    <bean class = "FieldMappingListFactoryBean">
        <property name = "mappings">
            <map>
                <entry name = "entitlement.user" value = "DocUsers" />
                <entry name = "entitlement.contributor" value = "DocContributors" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

However, if your field mappings are some kind of reusable DSL, you may try to think about implementing a [namespace extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to simulate an effect similar to a "import com.Foo;" in java code.  The best option I could find was to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with local properties defined.  Using your example, here's the configuration that you would put at the top of your spring config file to define a "class_FieldMapping" property:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <description>Define properties equivalent to "import foo;" in java source</description>
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="class_FieldMapping">com.company.product.longNamingStandard.migration.extractor.FieldMapping</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then, you can use that property within your beans:

```
<property name="mappingData">
  <list>                
    <bean class="${class_FieldMapping}">
      ...
    </bean>
    <bean class="${class_FieldMapping}">
      ...
    </bean>
  </list>
</property>
```

This has the benefit that use can also use it for things where you actually need the class name, and can't reference an instance of an object:

```
<util:constant static-field="${class_FieldMapping}.MYSTATICVAR" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare those inner beans as separate top-level beans with their own names, and then reference them in the list ?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I do this in some places, I should have included it in the example.I was hoping for a way to clean up the bean definitions in their own right. I'd prefer not to be using the class name 40 odd times in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

If I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer it leads to several exceptions in debug log. It works, but it seems it doesn't work on the first try.